# Como editar meus arquivos JS dentro do contêiner Docker usando o Sublime 3?

Tags: sublime-text, docker

Eu estou usando o Docker 1.7 no MAC OSX e criei um contêiner com um Apache e  uma aplicação WEB.

Gostaria de editar os fontes JS usando o Sublime Text 3.

Como posso fazer isso ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voce pode usar a funcionalidade **VOLUME** para isso.

Suponha que seu diretório de seu Dockerfile esteja em `~/Desktop/meu-site` e que o Document Root do site no Apache (Contêiner) esteja em `/var/www/html`

Faça o seguinte:

```
mkdir src
# copie o código de seu site para este diretório src
docker run -d -v ~/Desktop/meu-site/src:/var/www/html
```

Agora faça :

```
subl -a src
```

Altere um arquivo qualquer via Sublime Text e recarregue a página WEB.

Pronto ! Você verá a sua alteração

Comment: a especificação do volume na forma `~/Desktop/meu-site/src` funciona devido ao fato da shell MAC OSX ou Linux resolver o `~` para `/Users/usuário-logado` ou `/home/usuário-logado` dependendo do sistema operacional. Optei pelo uso do `~` para a instrução ficar portável.

Answer (score 0):

Mapeamento de volume é a maneira mais adequada para fazer isso.

Primeiro verifique qual local o seu container usa para ler os códigos que deseja manipular. Vamos imaginar que seja `/var/www/`.

Caso seu código esteja na pasta `/home/usuario/codigo`, o comando docker para fazer o mapeamento é o seguinte:

```
# docker -d -v /home/usuario/codigo:/var/www nome_da_imagem
```

Com isso, tudo que for adicionar e/ou modificado na pasta `/home/usuario/codigo` do host docker, será automaticamente modificado na pasta `/var/www` dentro do container.

> Observação, alguns serviços específicos precisam que o serviço seja reiniciado em caso de mudança no código, nesse caso, basta derrubar o container e iniciar novamente.

Para mais informações sobre mapeamento de volume:
https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/run/